# Web Analytics WebPart can't display Most Viewed Content

Tags: web-part, web-analytics

I have added a Web Analytics Webpart on my page and set it to display most viewed content.

It always says:

```
Most viewed pages
(under http://site/subsite)

There are no results to display.
```

Any help is appreciated

Comment: Any help for above Guys?